# ASP.NET MVC 3/4- Multiple view single controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on a MVC site which are having two separate views for mobile and web. The background work is same. So I want to have same controller for both view.

Following is folder structure for that.

View  -> Folder for view.

```
    Customer -> This folder is for web

                 Index.cshtml  -> Customer listing view for web

    MobileCustomer-> This folder is for mobile 

                 Index. cshtml -> Customer listing view for mobile.
```

Now the back ground things are same for both on the UI for both mobile and web are diffrerent. So I want to use same customer controller for that.  So in Controller folder of asp.net mvc project. I have customer controller and I want to use that same.

But I want URL for each mobile are different.

localhost/customer/         -> This will load normal view for customer

localhost/mobile/customer   -> This will load mobile view for customer

How I can achieve this with asp.net mvc 3 or 4 application?

Comment: Why you want different addresses for *mobile* and *web*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScottHa blogged about a [custom view engine](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek10NewMobileViewEnginesForASPNETMVC3SpeccompatibleWithASPNETMVC4.aspx) that you could use to separate your mobile views from your desktop client views and based on the user agent serve the one or the other. The NuGet is spec-compatible with the built-in functionality in ASP.NET MVC 4 so the migration will be easier for you. So if you are using ASP.NET MVC 3 go ahead, download the `MobileViewEngines` NuGet and start playing with it. And if you are using ASp.NET MVC4, well, that's already built-in for you.

Comment: Hi Darin I want different URL not the same URL and based on device it will detect the view.

Comment: Then simply tweak the NuGet (it has full source code available) so that in addition to using the User-Agent request header it uses the url as well when deciding which view to render. It should be trivially easy.

Comment: ok will try not sure its going to work or not. I tried it on asp.net mvc 4 where mobile view is also there but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

In follow up to Darin's response. ASP.NET MVC4 has a 'View Switcher' built in that is based upon MobileViewEngines.

An important detail left out is these view switchers first check for the presence of a cookie or some other variable such as a subdomain (the view preference) before deciding based on user agent. That way, someone on a mobile device can swap to the desktop view and vice versa.

The view switcher gets hooked into the ViewEngine, so that when you have a Customer Controller with an Index action which renders an Index.cshtml view, you might setup rules so that for mobile devices it would instead render the Index.mobile.cshtml view. You can create custom suffixes via settings that would use specialized views ex. Index.iphone.cshtml to render mobile device-specific views.

So essentially, using the new mechanics present in MVC4 your controllers and their actions would act normal, instead the view engines will render different views. If you want do something like in your scenario, I'd suggest you split off the MobileCustomer controller into an area -> Mobile(Area)->CustomerController-> etc.

Comment: I need diffrent url for both mobile and web is that possible with view switcher?

Comment: Also I don't want to switch controller because other wise why we should three separate concerns Model,Controller and View.

Answer (score 0):

I've been going through the source code of `ASP.NET MVC 4` and found some interesting things that may help you. **This is just my ideas I haven't tested this!**

We have to customize couple of things from the built-in features.

1. Find mobile views from separate folders.
2. The mobile version has to be rendered only if the url contains *mobile*.

We have to extend the `DefaultDisplayMode` class to select the mobile views from our custom folders. The `DefaultDisplayMode` is in `System.Web.WebPages` assembly. The base implementation of the `TransformPath` method converts the `virtualPath` from `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` to `/Views/Home/Index.Mobile.cshtml`.

We have to override the `TransformPath` method that will change the passed `virtualPath` for ex. from `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` to `/Views/MobileHome/Index.cshtml`.

```
public class CustomDisplayMode: DefaultDisplayMode
{
    // ...

    protected override string TransformPath(string virtualPath, string suffix)
    {
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(suffix))
       {
           return virtualPath;
       }

       // TO DO: modify the virtual path 
       // for ex. from /Views/Home/Index.cshtml to /Views/MobileHome/Index.cshtml

       return virtualPath;
    }
}
```

We have to set our `CustomDisplayMode` to `DisplayModeProvider` from the `Application`_Start. We can set the `ContextCondition` such that to consider the url into account.

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new CustomDefaultDisplayMode("Mobile")
{
    ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenBrowser().IsMobileDevice 
                         && check context.Request.Url contains the Mobile segment)
});
```